# Is there a website that hosts the strings application?

Tags: strings

Is there website where you can submit an executable and it will run it through strings and give you the output?

Comment: Any particular reason for that?

Comment: https://malwr.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.fileformat.info/tool/strings.htm
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​